# Expand long text lines of tree (nested HTML-lists) when mouse over in html/CSS/angular/bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have an angular 4 app with a div on the left where I show a tree of items as recursive HTML lists.
Long texts should be expanded over the border of the div and put in a shadowed box when the user moves the mouse over it like windows explorer does it. See the following screenshots.

Without mouse over:

[image: whithout mouse over]

With mouse over:

[image]

The long text is in a div on the left side of the page and is cut by the right div border. At the border you see a scroll bar. When I move the mouse over the long text I want the text to be desplayed beyond the border of the div so that it's whole content can be read.

I put Matthias' answer in a code snippet. It worked well in a flat list,
but I need a recursive tree like list, so it needs to be improved:

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 51px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}

.sidebar li {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: white;
}

.sidebar li:hover {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-none d-sm-block sidebar">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</span>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span>mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="col-sm-8 ml-sm-auto col-md-9 pt-3">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tooltip in other words? google 'tooltips' I'm sure that's what you want.

Comment: google "tooltip over element" did not help me

Comment: I don't want a tooltip above or below, I want the text itself fully visible

Comment: Please you gods of stackoverflow, reopen the question, there is a very constructive discussion running and a solution will soon be found!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a broad discussion system. It is a system where people could suggest discrete solutions to discrete problems.

Comment: that is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it is not too broad now.

Comment: finally I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50329565/show-complete-long-text-lines-of-tree-nested-html-lists-when-mouse-over-in-htm/50372125#50372125

Comment: but it does not scroll :-(

Answer (score 2):

You could change the `overflow` and `width` property when hovering the element, as a quick and simple solution. Try the snippet below, and please note, that `width: fit-content` does **NOT** work in Internet Explorer and Edge, since it is considered an [experimental feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content).

#### Support for `width: fit-content` (April 2018)

```
+-----------------------+-------------------+
| Google Chrome         | 22.0 (-webkit)    |
|                       | 46.0              |
+-----------------------+-------------------|
| Mozilla Firefox       | 3.0 (-moz)        |
+-----------------------+-------------------|
| Internet Explorer     | X                 |
+-----------------------+-------------------|
| Opera                 | 15 (-webkit)      |
+-----------------------+-------------------|
| Safari                | 6.1 (-webkit)     |
+-----------------------+-------------------|
| Microsoft Edge        | X                 |
+-----------------------+-------------------|
```

[Source 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Browser_compatibility)

[Source 2](https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content)

#### Edit

I played around with the code from your updated question, and you may want to take a look at the snippet below. I just applied the `overflow` style to the `<li>` element instead of the whole `sidebar` wrapper.

**Pleas note:** Since the dot in a list is outside of the element by default, the `overflow-x` property will hide it. So I decided to also hide it when you hover the element. If you *really* need this dot, you could either override the default value with `list-style-position: inside` (causes a nasty line break) or you could try to fake the dots with the `::before` pseudo element.

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 51px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}

.sidebar li {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: white;
}

.sidebar li:hover {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-none d-sm-block sidebar">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</li>
          <li>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</li>
          <li>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="col-sm-8 ml-sm-auto col-md-9 pt-3">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, but does not work with multiple text lines in a div

Comment: can you give me an example how your div would look like?

Comment: yes, I put your solution into my questsion

Comment: thank you! I updated my answer as well

Comment: Does it work for you? In my browser the box doesn't bo beyond the div and the long text is mixed with the lore ipsum text, which looks ugly. Firefox 52 and 59. Tried it now in Chrome, there it works!

Comment: @user3725805 You are absolutely right! Thanks for the hint, I added some vendor-prefixes, it should work better now. Only Edge and IE seem to lack support for this property :(

Comment: good solution, unfortunately I have a tree like recursive list. Edited my snippet, do you have a solution?