# Show complete long text lines of tree (nested HTML-lists) when mouse over in html/CSS/angular/bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have an angular 4 app with a div on the left where I show a tree of items as recursive HTML lists.
Long texts should be expanded over the border of the div and put in a shadowed box when the user moves the mouse over it like windows explorer does it. See the following screenshots.

Without mouse over:

[image: whithout mouse over]

With mouse over:

[image]

The long text is in a div on the left side of the page and is cut by the right div border. At the border you see a scroll bar. When I move the mouse over the long text I want the text to be desplayed beyond the border of the div so that it's whole content can be read.

I have a solution where the whole enclosing List-Element is raised,
so it needs to be improved:

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 51px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}

.sidebar li {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: white;
}

.sidebar li:hover {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-none d-sm-block sidebar">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</span>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span>mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="col-sm-8 ml-sm-auto col-md-9 pt-3">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap v4 (which you are using) includes [tether.io](http://tether.io/) for placing dropdowns, tootips and modals on any target element you want, while keeping their position relative to the element opening them. The simple fix is to use provided bootstrap functionaliy (using `.tooltip()` !?). If you want to have complete control, you can use the `tether.io` library directly.

Comment: Actually Tether has been replaced with PopperJS in the stable release.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by changing the HTML structure. Now I have  inside of , but it works.

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 51px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}

.sidebar li {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: white;
}

.sidebar li:hover {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-none d-sm-block sidebar">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</span>
          </li>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span>mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="col-sm-8 ml-sm-auto col-md-9 pt-3">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```